# React Native IOS Messaging with FireBase

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Following this documentation https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup . It did not talk about any changes in apdelegate.mm file for getting push notification. It did not talk about changes in Pod file. Is there any working sample Git hub project where Firebase messaging work with React native for IOS ? Or any documentation which describe excat changes required in apdelegate.mm and pod file to make it work ? I am using React native "0.71.7"

Followed Document https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup and want to get push notification in React native IOS